# IE7 ignores :not-selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Internet Explorer 7 seems to ignore the :not-selector in the second line in following example, it shows and then hides the content - instead of showing the content with the right index and hiding the rest.

```
$('.dashboard-module-content:eq(' + indexFoo + ') .expand-collapse').show('fast');
$('.dashboard-module-content:not(:eq(' + indexFoo + ')) .expand-collapse').hide('fast');
```

Anyone knows who to tackle a problem like this?

Comment: can you also show the relevant HTML as well please? Without seeing that, it's difficult to know what is wrong in the context in which `:not` is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery pseudo selector `:eq()` is in relation to the result set, not to the position inside a parent, etc. Try this:

```
$(".dashboard-module-content .expand-collapse")
   .eq(indexFoo).show('fast').end()
   .not(':eq(' + indexFoo + ')').hide('fast');
```

I assumed there is a 1:1 ratio of `.dashboard-module-content` to `.expand-collapse`. (Each dashboard module contains only one expand collapse block)

This block is also a little more optimized as it is not collecting all the `.dashboard-module-content` blocks twice per execution.